# Woocommerce specific banner product category and childs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've searched a lot and I did not find any specific to this, or at least, my development skills are yet not great, if someone can help I appreciate.

My goal is to show a text on each product that is inside the category X or sub-category of that same X.

For example:
Fruits
-Bananas

If the bellow product is inside Bananas it will show the code too because belongs to Fruits.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'single_product_short_description', 10, 1 );
function single_product_short_description( $post_excerpt ){

    if ( is_product_category(array(140,20)) )
        $post_excerpt = $post_excerpt. '<br><div class="product-message"><p>' . __( "Whats the measure? <a href='/#right-measure' target='_blank'>Check</a>.", "woocommerce" ) . '</p></div>'; 

    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

I know my code is not good because each time the client add a sub-category I have to fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed doing this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'single_product_short_description', 10, 1 );
function single_product_short_description( $post_excerpt ){
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;

if ( in_array( 'piercings', $categories ) || in_array( 'piercings-en', $categories ) ) {
  $post_excerpt = $post_excerpt. '<br><div class="product-message"><p>' . __( "Bla bla bla", "woocommerce" ) . '</p></div>';
}

return $post_excerpt;
}
```

Hope this helps someone